# Are positive Vieta's equations sufficient for negative roots?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots

Let $n$ (unknown) real numbers $x_i$ be given. Suppose all Vieta's coefficient equations are positive, i.e.
$$
a_1  = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i > 0\\
a_2  =\sum_{(i>j)} x_i x_j > 0\\
a_3  =\sum_{(i>j>k)} x_i x_j x_k> 0\\
\dots \\
a_n  =\prod_{i=1}^n x_i > 0
$$
where the sums go over all possible indicated pairs, triples, ... , $n$-tupels.

**Question**: Are these conditions sufficient to show that all $x_i>0$?

I observed that this is linked to roots of polynomials. Let $a_0=1$. We have the identity (Vieta):
$$
p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x + x_i) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^{n-k}
$$
The roots of the polynomial $p(x)$ are given by $-x_i$, so if all roots are negative, then all $x_i$ are positive and all Vieta's coefficients are positive. The question asks for the other way.

For $n=2$, it is easy to show that it's true. For higher $n$, it will become cumbersome / impossible to give an analytic solution of the roots, since it is known that no such analytic solutions exist for $n >4$.

Before I start trying to produce (numerical) counterexamples, I ask if there is an already existing answer to this question.

Comment: If all $a_k$ are positive then $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k x^{n-k}$ cannot have a positive root. Am I overlooking or misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MartinR Your statement would be the (affirming) answer to my question.  So: why can there be no positive root?

Comment: If $p(x)$ has (real) positive coefficients then $x > 0$ implies $p(x) >0$, trivially.

Comment: @MartinR So this gives a proof by contradiction, right?

Comment: There should be no $\binom{n}{k}$ in the Vieta identity, should it?

Comment: @user You're right, I deleted it.

Comment: How are you going to check, that $a_k$ can be represented as Vieta composition of _real_ numbers?

Comment: @user I said in the question that we are not given "just" positive $a_i$, but that we are given $a_i$'s as specified, i.e. composed from real $x_i$ which however are unknown to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $a_k$ are the [“elementary symmetric polynomials”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) of 
$x_1, \ldots, x_n$. If all $a_k$ are positive then
$$
 p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x + x_i) = \sum_{k=0}^n  a_k x^{n-k}
$$
is a polynomial with real, strictly positive coefficients.

If $x_i \le 0$ for some $i$ then
$$
 0 = p(-x_i) = a_n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  a_k (-x_i)^{n-k} > 0
$$
gives a contradiction.

So yes, if $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are given *real* numbers and all
their elementary symmetric polynomials $a_k$ are positive, then all
$x_i$ are necessarily positive.

If the $x_i$ are complex numbers and the $a_k$ are positive real
numbers then one can only conclude that the $x_i$ are not zero
or negative real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your definition of $a_1,...,a_n$, each of $x_1,...,x_n$ is a root of
$$x^n -a_1 x^{n-1} + a_2 x^{n-2} + \cdots + (-1)^na_n=0$$
Note the alternating signs.

Now suppose $a_1,...,a_n > 0$.

Then none of the roots can be zero (since the constant term is nonzero).

Moreover, none of the roots can be negative either, since if $x_1<0$ and $n$ is even, then substituting $x_1$ for $x$, all terms on the $\text{LHS}$ of the equation would be positive, and if $x_1<0$ and $n$ is odd, then substituting $x_1$ for $x$, all terms on the $\text{LHS}$ of the equation would be negative.

Hence, if any of $x_1,...,x_n$ are real, they must be positive.

Comment: For odd $n$, none of the roots can be negative either.

Comment: Thanks (it was a momentary blind spot), but now it's clear. I've edited it accordingly.